# Ordering by multiple columns including Count in PySpark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I am currently working on understanding Pyspark, and am running into a problem. I am attempting to resolve how to order by multiple columns in the dataframe, when one of these is a count.

As an example, say I have a dataframe (df) with three columns, A,B,and C. I want to group by A and B, and then count these instances. So if there are 10 instances where A=1 and B=1, the Table for that row should look like:

A|B|Count

1 1 10

I have determined that I can do this fairly easily by running:

df.groupBy('A', 'B').count()

Then if I want to order this dataframe by count (descending), this is also pretty straightforward:

df.groupBy('A', 'B').count().orderBy(desc("count"))

This next step is where I am having trouble. What if now I want to also order by column C, ie order first by count, and then by C? I had thought that the syntax would be something akin to:

df.groupBy('A', 'B').count().orderBy(desc("count"), desc("C"))

But this does not work, presumably because once I run count(), the dataframe is limited to only the columns A, B, and count. Do I need to somehow create a new column in the original dataframe with the count column, and if so, how can I do this?

Is there another simpler way that I am missing to order by both count and C?

For clarity an example dataframe that I would like to end with could appear as:

A|B|Count|C

1 1 10    5

1 2 9     3

1 5 9     1

2 4 8     10

2 7 8     5

Any insights or guidance are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you group by A & B and perform count, the only way of getting column C is by use some aggregation method that also provide you column C (for example, first() function which for every occurrence of A & B it will return the first C value.

But yet, I don't get what you are trying to get.
If you want to order By C you will have to F.count("C").alias("countsC") and then you will have it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a window Function , the column 'C' is not in the group by, hence is not available for order/sorting the columns. If you just want the grouped columns eg A,B and the count column, you can always use select statement to get just that after the window function.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("A","B")
df.withColumn('count',F.count('*').over(windowSpec)).select("A","B","count").distinct().orderBy(F.col('count').desc(),F.col('C').desc()).show()
```